# Global Application Menu in Ubuntu 18.10 / 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, 19.04

I would very much like to move my application menu to the top bar.
In Ubuntu 18.04 this was very easily achieved using the [Gnome Global Application Menu Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/).
Unfortunately, that extension has not been maintained for some time and it does not work in Ubuntu 18.10 or 19.04.

Does anyone have a solution for this that works in 18.10 and 19.04 (or at least for the latter)?

Comment: The problem of why the un-mantained extension not work is just because is exactly not manteined and nothing else. Therefore, it can work the same, if it is updated to support the changes in the new gnome-shell code. Most of time it's better provide the "gnome-shell --version" than the ubuntu versions, because the incompatibilities of an extension of GNOME is allways much more related with a shell change than any other thing. The current case is not different.